# Why are boolean and foreign key id indexes 1/3rd the size of the entire table?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that is 3327 MB with ~35 columns. Most of the columns are boolean values or foreign key id references. The part I'm trying to understand is why most of the boolean indexes takes up 1091MB and the foreign key ids (int) 1090MB.

Comment: Having index on boolean is not a good idea in first place as the boolean column has low cardinality field. Instead, you may want to use [Partial Indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html). The size of the foreign key index really depends on how many unique ids you have stored at given table and can easily be the size you see.

Comment: Also, as you said most of your 35 columns are boolean. Boolean storage takes 1 byte while integer takes 4 bytes. So, you can do the easy math with how many rows you have and how much does those IDs column overall take storage amount of your table. But what I see atm, is fully normal result if your description is true :)

Comment: Turns out this is just really bad bloat. Running pg_repack on the offensive tables brought down the the database 54% and the indexes 73%. Thanks for everyones comments.

Comment: The only time an index on bools makes much sense is when they're 99% one value and you index the other. Aka: create index on table(boolfield) where boolfield is true; when 99% of the entries are false.

Also compound indexes, esp where the bools are sparsely populated with one value.

Answer (score 0):

> The part I'm trying to understand is why most of the boolean indexes takes up 1091MB and the foreign key ids (int) 1090MB.

An index is always 8 bytes at the least. That means even if you just index one bool, you're wasting 7 bytes in storage.

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT true AS bar, 42 AS baz
  FROM generate_series(1,1e6);

CREATE INDEX ON foo(bar);
CREATE INDEX ON foo(baz);
CREATE INDEX ON foo(bar,baz);

test=# \d+ foo
                         Table "public.foo"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description 
--------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 bar    | boolean |           | plain   |              | 
 baz    | integer |           | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    "foo_bar_baz_idx" btree (bar, baz)
    "foo_bar_idx" btree (bar)
    "foo_baz_idx" btree (baz)

test=# \di+ foo*
                             List of relations
 Schema |      Name       | Type  |  Owner   | Table | Size  | Description 
--------+-----------------+-------+----------+-------+-------+-------------
 public | foo_bar_baz_idx | index | ecarroll | foo   | 21 MB | 
 public | foo_bar_idx     | index | ecarroll | foo   | 21 MB | 
 public | foo_baz_idx     | index | ecarroll | foo   | 21 MB | 
(3 rows)
```